# Cannot use the RenderModeInteractiveServer attribute

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am following a tutorial in YouTube for Blazor in .net 8. There is a portion that I need to use this line of code in the pages section

```
@page "/games"

@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer(false)]
```

The problem lies with RenderModeInteractiveServer(false).

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RenderModeInteractiveServerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BlazorCrudNet8  D:\Tryouts\Blazor\Net8\BlazorCrudNet8\BlazorCrudNet8\Components\Pages\GameList.razor    7   Active
```

On research, I can use this

```
@page "/games"

@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]
```

The problem is when I get to the "games" page, it flickers. It's like it reloads or something like that.

Comment: Any update? Do you have any other question?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52048), you could find we should add `@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode` to `_imports.razor` file instead of `@Attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]` use `@rendermode InteractiveServer`.

> The problem is when I get to the "games" page, it flickers. It's like it reloads or something like that.

If you don't put other specific codes inside the code in games page, it will not flickers(refresh the whole page).

I suggest you could try to update your VS to the newest version and use newest .net 8 to create the Blazor web app with server app mode to see if this error is still existing or not.